# Embed Youtube on a Webpage to be viewed from Smart TV

Tags: html, youtube-api, samsung-smart-tv

Simple question...

I am making a small webpage that should be viewed from a SmartTV. This page serves some Ajax calls etc.

But the site also shows a Youtube video. The problem is that Youtube video shows up as Flash content. The smart TV doesn't play flash, so I'm in trouble.

Anyone have any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Does the smart TV allow HTML5 `<video>`? If so, youtube has been testing with HTML5 video, I'm just not sure if the API can request HTML5 video.

Comment: ok, i'll look into that. One thing I did read about, since a TV is not a mobile device, youtube doesn't go to m.youtube.com site which should be flash-free. I'll try forcing the mobile site onto the TV hopefully that works.

Comment: @CogentP Check my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I wanted to do the exact same thing. This is how implemented this logic. And it is working fine for me.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="webElement" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**JS:**

When ajax call is received (contains many files of type YouTube/WebPages/MP4 files):

```
if (Utility.isYouTube(dr.FileName)) {  
dr.IsWeb = true;  
dr.WebUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Utility.getParameterByName('v', dr.FileName) + "?rel=0&autoplay=1";  
}
```

This is how I played it (if webpage/Youtube):

```
var webElement = jQuery("#webElement");  
webElement.empty();  
var obj = "<object type='text/html' width='1920' height='1080' data='" + dr.WebUrl + "' onerror='Player.onWebElementError();'> </object>";  
webElement.append(obj);  
webElement.show();
```

Hope it will help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung SmartTVs do use Flash. It depends on which TV you want your app to run. If you are developing for 2011 it will be a no go, since 2011 SmartTV models only support AS2.0 and YouTube has stopped supporting AS2.0 for their API. 
For 2012 and 2013 models you can easily embed a YouTube video by doing:
`var attributes = { id: "myytplayer" }, params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", allowFullScreen: "true"};`

`swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=2&fs=1', "ytplayer",400, 600, "6", null, null, params, attributes);`

Then to load a video:
`ytp.getVideo('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubAjEjkJIJo');`

   `ytp.getVideo = function (url) {`
    
    `//loads video by url`
         `ytp.ytp_ref.cueVideoByUrl(url);`
`};`